# how to close Chrome tab in Vaadin 7?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin application, when user click on a button, the current Chrome stab should close.
I have tried these methods:

```
UI.getCurrent().close()
```

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().close()
```

but none of them work. The page appears to be disabled with all the button gray out and not clickable, but the chrome tab is still there.

I also tried
`UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("window.close();")`
But this works on IE and NOT on Chrome due to Chrome's security concern.

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: If there would be a way of circumventing the security precaution in Chrome, then the Chrome team would add additional restrictions in an upcoming version. The basic rule is that a user has opened a tab on their own, then it's also up to the user to control how its closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `open(location, '_self').close();`.

Comment: is this what you mean? ```UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("window.open('','_self');window.close();") ```I tried that, chrome tab still not close and I got this message from Chrome console. ```Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it```

Comment: No. I meant `UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("open(location, '_self').close()");`.

Comment: same problem ```Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it```